# Import json file to DynamoDB via AWS Data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to figure out how I can create an AWS data pipeline that can take a json file from S3 and import this into a DynamoDB table. I'm able to create some java code that achieves this but I want to do it through Data pipeline. I can see there are templates for exporting from DynamoDB to S3 and importing a backup but I'm struggling to figure out how to import a plain json file.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation you will find an example of importing and exporting data from DynamoDb (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html)

Here's how it is described in the documentation:

> To create the pipeline
>
> Open the AWS Data Pipeline console at
>
> The first screen that you see depends on whether you've created a
>   pipeline in the current region.
>
> If you haven't created a pipeline in this region, the console displays
>   an introductory screen. Choose Get started now.
>
> If you've already created a pipeline in this region, the console
>   displays a page that lists your pipelines for the region. Choose
>   Create new pipeline.
>
> In Name, enter a name for your pipeline.
>
> (Optional) In Description, enter a description for your pipeline.
>
> For Source, select Build using a template, and then select the
>   following template: Import DynamoDB backup data from S3.
>
> Under Parameters, set Input S3 folder to
>   s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/Store/ProductCatalog, which is a sample
>   data source, and set DynamoDB table name to the name of your table.
>
> Under Schedule, choose on pipeline activation.
>
> Under Pipeline Configuration, leave logging enabled. Choose the folder
>   icon under S3 location for logs, select one of your buckets or
>   folders, and then choose Select.
>
> If you prefer, you can disable logging instead.
>
> Under Security/Access, leave IAM roles set to Default.
>
> Click Edit in Architect.
>
> Next, configure the Amazon SNS notification actions that AWS Data
>   Pipeline performs depending on the outcome of the activity.
>
> To configure the success and failure actions
>
> In the right pane, click Activities.
>
> From Add an optional field, select On Success.
>
> From the newly added On Success, select Create new: Action.
>
> From Add an optional field, select On Fail.
>
> From the newly added On Fail, select Create new: Action.
>
> In the right pane, click Others.
>
> For DefaultAction1, do the following:
>
> Change the name to SuccessSnsAlarm.
>
> From Type, select SnsAlarm.
>
> In Topic Arn, enter the ARN of the topic that you created.
>
> Enter a subject and a message.
>
> For DefaultAction2, do the following:
>
> Change the name to FailureSnsAlarm.
>
> From Type, select SnsAlarm.
>
> In Topic Arn, enter the ARN of the topic that you created.
>
> Enter a subject and a message.

The public github site has some samples for working with DynamoDB  (https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples). Here's an example of a pipeline definition:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "occurrences": "1",
            "period": "1 Day",
            "name": "RunOnce",
            "id": "DefaultSchedule",
            "type": "Schedule",
            "startAt": "FIRST_ACTIVATION_DATE_TIME",
        "maxActiveInstances" : "1"
        },
        {
            "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
            "schedule": {
                "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
            },
            "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
            "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
            "pipelineLogUri": "s3://",
            "scheduleType": "cron",
            "name": "Default",
            "id": "Default"
        },
        {
            "maximumRetries": "2",
            "name": "TableBackupActivity",
            "step": "s3://dynamodb-emr-us-east-1/emr-ddb-storage-handler/2.1.0/emr-ddb-2.1.0.jar,org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDbExport,#{myOutputS3Loc}/#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')},#{myDDBTableName},#{myDDBReadThroughputRatio}",
            "id": "TableBackupActivity",
            "runsOn": {
                "ref": "EmrClusterForBackup"
            },
            "type": "EmrActivity"
        },
        {
            "bootstrapAction": "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop, --yarn-key-value, yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=12800,--yarn-key-value,yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=256,--mapred-key-value,mapreduce.map.memory.mb=500,--mapred-key-value,mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx400M,--mapred-key-value,mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=1,--mapred-key-value,mapreduce.map.speculative=false",
            "name": "EmrClusterForBackup",
            "amiVersion": "3.8.0",
            "id": "EmrClusterForBackup",
            "type": "EmrCluster",
            "masterInstanceType": "m1.medium",
            "coreInstanceType": "#{myInstanceType}",
            "coreInstanceCount": "#{myInstanceCount}",
        "terminateAfter" : "12 hours"
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [
        {
            "description": "OutputS3folder",
            "id": "myOutputS3Loc",
            "type": "AWS::S3::ObjectKey"
        },
        {
            "default": "0.2",
            "watermark": "Valuebetween0.1-1.0",
            "description": "DynamoDB Read Throughput Ratio",
            "id": "myDDBReadThroughputRatio",
            "type": "Double"
        },
        {
            "description": "DynamoDB Table Name",
            "id": "myDDBTableName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "description": "Instance Type",
            "id": "myInstanceType",
            "watermark" : "Use m1.medium if Read Capacity Units for the job <= 900. Else use m3.xlarge",
            "type": "String",
            "default": "m3.xlarge"
        },
        {
            "description": "Instance Count",
        "watermark" : "(Read Capacity Units / 300) for m1.medium if RCU <= 900. Else (RCU / 1500) for m3.xlarge",
            "id": "myInstanceCount",
            "type": "Integer",
            "default": "1"
        },
    {
        "description" : "Burst IOPs",
        "watermark"   : "Add IOPS to the DDB table by this percent for the duration of the export job",
            "id"          : "myBurstIOPS",
            "type"     :    "Double",
            "default"     : "0.0"
    }
    ]
}
```